# Split String by length

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

I have a string value that its length is 5000 + characters long , i want to split this into 76 characters long with a new line at the end of each 76 characters. how woudld i do this in c#?

Comment: What Aric said, but are you sure you want to split in the middle of a word?

Comment: Writing an email client?

Comment: Or are you working on a UUEncode?

Comment: I using base64 Encode and writeing it to an XML

Comment: Sounds like a pretty normal reason to do this

Comment: @Mart, isn't this a duplicate of your earlier question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009620/linq-to-xml-base64-encoded

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're writing Base64 data, try writing

```
Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
```

This will insert a newline every 76 characters

Comment: I'll be damned, so it will.  Should be fast too, uses unsafe code. ;)

Comment: pretty sure this is the winner becasue the others would have to run though this converter anyway

Answer (score 4):

A little uglier ... but much faster ;) (this version took 161 ticks... Aric's took 413)

I posted my test code on my blog. http://hackersbasement.com/?p=134
(I also found StringBuilder to be much slower than string.Join)

http://hackersbasement.com/?p=139 <= updated results

```
    string chopMe = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    char[] chopMeArray = chopMe.ToCharArray();
    int totalLength = chopMe.Length;
    int partLength = 12;
    int partCount = (totalLength / partLength) + ((totalLength % partLength == 0) ? 0 : 1);
    int posIndex = 0;
    char[] part = new char[partLength];
    string[] parts = new string[partCount];
    int get = partLength;
    for (int i = 0; i < partCount; i++)
    {
        get = Math.Min(partLength, totalLength - posIndex);
        Array.Copy(chopMeArray, posIndex, part, 0, get);
        parts[i] = new string(part, 0, get);
        posIndex += partLength;
    }

    var output = string.Join("\r\n", parts) + "\r\n";
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
```

Comment: what do you think if my answer?

Comment: I've updated my answer - you might want to run your benchmark again ;)

Comment: Also, it's " StopWatch sw = StopWatch.StartNew(); "

Comment: I don't see it yet.  Anyway, if I'm doing the benchmark correctly mine runs in about 40 ticks on average.

Comment: I updated my site again.  (the ticks are the comments next to the Console.WriteLine()s) ... and Joel you are right I wasn't resetting the timer. This shows StringBuilder versions to be the fastest now.

Comment: I have tried to keep them all in line but i will change them back to methods shortly and run it again

Comment: Okay, you mean on the blog post you linked.  I see it now.  I don't think you really got the point of the code I posted.  Note that I _never_ concatenate any strings.  It's all copying from buffer to buffer, and I create the result by calling the string constructor directly.

Comment: Another suggestion: you really need two sets of benchmarks.  One with a shorter string (say, 40 characters) and another with a very long string (say, 2000 characters).

Comment: Yeah I was trying to make that part similar for all of the tests to remove it from the picture.  But I am working on a cleaner version that is pretty much a direct copy of each persons code shortly

Comment: @Matthew, Look my latest edit again, this one should be way faster :-)

Comment: what type of computer do you have? On my computer, taking what you have on your website and switching my old code with my new code from this thread I get: #1 39464, #2 48784, #341160, #4 45552, #5 8000, #6 1109656 (running inside visual studio, debugging mode)

Comment: Windows Vista Ultimate, AMD Althon 64 X2 Dual Core 6000+ (3.0 GHz), 4GB RAM (Dual Core 64 bit) ... with a bunch of crap running at the same time

Comment: @Fredou: 1109656 is a _long_ time in computer terms.  You're doing something wrong with the benchmarks.

Comment: @Joel, I have an Intel processor? maybe that is why...

I just copy/pasted into VS and ran it

Comment: @Matthew, again, I updated my answer and it's about 40% faster than the previous one on my computer. If you want to updated your bench on your website, go ahead.

Answer (score 4):

A side on this, if you want StringBuilder versus string performance the best article is the codeproject one found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/StringBuilder_vs_String.aspx).

[image]

*(This doesn't show string size however)*

In a nutshell, StringBuilder isn't faster until a threshold is met with the string length (or repeated contactenation), which you're well under, so stick the regular string concatenation and String methods.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<=\G.{76})", "\r\n");
```

EDIT: Apparently, this is the slowest method of all those posted so far.  I wonder how it does if you pre-compile the regex:

```
Regex rx0 = new Regex(@"(?<=\G.{76})");

s = rx0.Replace(s, "\r\n"); // only time this portion
```

Also, how does it compare to a straight matching approach?

```
Regex rx1 = new Regex(".{76}");

s = rx1.Replace(s, "$0\r\n"); // only time this portion
```

I've always wondered how expensive those unbounded lookbehinds are.

Comment: :D  One-liners: the programmers' version of haiku.

Comment: Alan, your first version wasn't as slow as I originally said.  Joel pointed out I wasn’t resetting the timer.  You can check you time on my blog post.  And I will shortly be making a new post with everyone’s code refactored into methods.

Comment: Cool. But you've got a copy/paste error there: AlanM_3() is doing exactly the same thing as AlanM_1().

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string InsertNewLine(string s, int len)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length + (int)(s.Length/len) + 1);
    int start = 0;
    for (start=0; start<s.Length-len; start+=len)
    {
        sb.Append(s.Substring(start, len));
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    sb.Append(s.Substring(start));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

where **s** would be your input string and **len** the desired line length (76).

Comment: +1 for being the canonical solution, and EXACTLY what was asked for.

Comment: The best way to use line breaks is using: Environment.NewLine, instead of "\n".

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] FixedSplit(string s, int len)
{
   List<string> output;
   while (s.Length > len)
   {
      output.Add(s.Substring(0, len) + "\n");
      s.Remove(0, len);
   }
   output.Add(s + "\n");
   return output.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: ...with the provision that if you wanted a single string back, you would have to spin through the returned array and mash all of the strings back together.

Comment: How would i do that, as i do need 1 string back?

Comment: string.Join("\r\n",output) + "\r\n"

Comment: That should work too, but you don't need the \r\n's, as newlines have already been put in by Aric.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitString(string s, int length)
{
    var buf = new char[length];
    using (var rdr = new StringReader(s))
    {
        int l;
        l = rdr.ReadBlock(buf, 0, length);
        while (l > 0)
        {
            yield return (new string(buf, 0, l)) + Environment.NewLine;
            l = rdr.ReadBlock(buf, 0, length);
        }
    }
}
```

Then to put them back together:

```
string theString = GetLongString();
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(theString.Length + theString.Length/76);
foreach (string s in SplitString(theString, 76) { buf.Append(s); }
string result = buf.ToString();
```

Or you could do this:

```
string InsertNewLines(string s, int interval)
{
    char[] buf = new char[s.Length + (int)Math.Ceiling(s.Length / (double)interval)];

    using (var rdr = new StringReader(s))
    {
        for (int i=0; i<buf.Length-interval; i++)
        {
            rdr.ReadBlock(buf, i, interval);
            i+=interval;
            buf[i] = '\n';
        }
        if (i < s.Length)
        {
            rdr.ReadBlock(buf, i, s.Length - i);
            buf[buf.Length - 1] = '\n';
        }
    }
    return new string(buf);
}
```

Comment: This would handle large files better.  But it's pretty slow

Comment: The main advantage is that this makes it easy to change the function to accept a plain stream. Then you could pass something like a file stream to it and maybe never load the entire string in memory initially in the first place.

Comment: Added a new method that put the result directly into a buffer - should be very fast.

Comment: @Joel, from Matthew post you said I had wrong ticks, you were right and I found out why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017608/about-the-stopwatch-elapsedticks

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this would be what I would use, I think

```
    static string fredou()
    {
        string s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        int partLength = 12;

        int stringLength = s.Length;
        StringBuilder n = new StringBuilder(stringLength + (int)(stringLength / partLength) + 1);
        int chopSize = 0;
        int pos = 0;

        while (pos < stringLength)
        {
            chopSize = (pos + partLength) < stringLength ? partLength : stringLength - pos;
            n.Append(s , pos, chopSize);
            n.Append("\r\n");
            pos += chopSize;
        }

        return n.ToString();         
    }
```

by looking at AppendLine under reflector:

```
    <ComVisible(False)> _
    Public Function AppendLine(ByVal value As String) As StringBuilder
        Me.Append(value)
        Return Me.Append(Environment.NewLine)
    End Function

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property NewLine As String
        Get
            Return ChrW(13) & ChrW(10)
        End Get
    End Property
```

For me, speed wise, doing it manually > AppendLine

Comment: Well you won the slowest (279097 ticks)

Comment: Yes, definitely the regex wins!

Comment: The first for loop doesn't count for time in Fredou's solution, since it builds the test string.  Is it still 270K ticks?  I read the first for loop as 7000 new string initializations.

Comment: (I really don't think you want to do this the way you did... but we will see)

Comment: Use AppendLine() instead of calling Append() twice.  Also becasue of the way .Net handles strings you will probably see a decrease in memory usage as well. I have to call it a night but feel free to post your results as a comment on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

One more.... (first time through slowish, subsequent runs, similar to the faster times posted above)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string chopMe = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
  sw.Start();
  string result = string.Join("\r\n", ChopString(chopMe).ToArray());
  sw.Stop();
  MessageBox.Show(result + " " + sw.ToString());
}


public IEnumerable<string> ChopString(string s)
{
  int i = 0;
  while (i < s.Length)
  {
    yield return i + PARTLENGTH <= s.Length ? s.Substring(i,PARTLENGTH) :s.Substring(i) ;
    i += PARTLENGTH;
  }
}
```

Edit: I was curious to see how fast substring was...

Comment: You make a good point.  for me next test I will loop them all twice.  The way string work the first to parse would the the slowest.

Answer (score 0):

The string is 5000 characters... I don't think speed is really of the essence unless you're doing this thousands or maybe even millions of times, especially when the OP didn't even mention speed being important. Premature optimization?

I would probably use recursion as it will, in my opinion, lead to the simplest code.

This may not be syntatically correct, as I know .NET but not C#.

```
String ChunkString(String s, Integer chunkLength) {
    if (s.Length <= chunkLength) return s;
    return String.Concat(s.Substring(0, chunkLength), 
                         ChunkString(s.Substring(chunkLength)));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, we know that; we're only doing the benchmarking to satisfy our curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

mostly for the fun of it, here's a different solution implemented as extension method to string:
(\r\n used explicitly so will only support that format for newline);

```
public static string Split(this string str, int len)
        {
            char org = str.ToCharArray();
            int parts = str.Length / len + (str.Length % len == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            int stepSize = len + newline.Length;
            char[] result = new char[parts * stepSize];
            int resLen = result.Length;

            for (int i =0;i<resLen ;i+stepSize)
            {
                Array.Copy(org,i*len,result,i*stepSize);
                resLen[i++] = '\r';
                resLen[i++] = '\n';
            }
            return new string(result);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm spliting the string by 35

```
var tempstore ="12345678901234567890123456789012345";
for (int k = 0; k < tempstore.Length; k += 35)
{
   PMSIMTRequest.Append(tempstore.Substring(k, tempstore.Length - k > 35 ? 35 : tempstore.Length - k));
   PMSIMTRequest.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
}
messagebox.Show(PMSIMTRequest.tostring());
```

Answer (score 0):

@M4N's answer is very good , but I think `while statement` is easier to understand than `for statement`.

```
public static string InsertNewLine(string source, int len = 76)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(source.Length + (int)(source.Length / len) + 1);
    var start = 0;
    while ((start + len) < source.Length)
    {
        sb.Append(source.Substring(start, len));
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        start += len;
    }
    sb.Append(source.Substring(start));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```