# Are Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks and Stopwatch.Elapsed.Ticks always the same?

Tags: .net, stopwatch

What does `ElapsedTicks` and `Elapsed.Ticks` in the Stopwatch class mean? When could the meaning be different than intended?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I just found out that `ElapsedTicks` in the `Stopwatch` class doesn't mean real "ticks" if [`StopWatch.IsHighResolution`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution) is `true`.

Note (if `IsHighResolution` is True - from [Microsoft Connect link (now dead)](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=357164)):

> Stopwatch ticks are different from
> DateTime.Ticks. Each tick in the
> DateTime.Ticks value represents
> one 100-nanosecond interval. Each tick
> in the ElapsedTicks value represents
> the time interval equal to 1 second
> divided by the Frequency.

You can do the math above or it seem you can use `StopWatch.Elapsed.Ticks` instead of `StopWatch.ElapsedTicks`.

Answer (score 12):

```
Elapsed.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond == ElapsedTicks / Stopwatch.Frequency
```

Of course this may not exactly equal due to rounding, as Stopwatch ticks and TimeSpan ticks are measured in different units. Also, in case you executed the above code literally, obviously some ticks would elapse between taking the value of `Elapsed.Ticks` and that of `ElapsedTicks`.