# Differences in Elapsed Ticks property of Stopwatch

Tags: c#, .net, stopwatch, elapsedtime

ElapsedTicks & Elapsed.Ticks are properties of Stopwatch, which I think should be same.
And in case they are same, why they should give different outputs ?

Code :

```
Stopwatch spwt = Stopwatch.StartNew();
spwt.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(spwt.ElapsedTicks);
Console.WriteLine(spwt.Elapsed.Ticks);
```

Output :

```
6
16
```

Why is this difference observed ? shouldn't it be same ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are StopWatch.ElapsedTicks and StopWatch.Elapsed.Ticks always the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017608/are-stopwatch-elapsedticks-and-stopwatch-elapsed-ticks-always-the-same)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks#remarks :

> **Note**
>
> Stopwatch ticks are different from DateTime.Ticks. Each tick in the DateTime.Ticks value represents one 100-nanosecond interval. Each tick in the ElapsedTicks value represents the time interval equal to 1 second divided by the Frequency.