# Should I call Stop before reading ElapsedMilliseconds?

Tags: c#, stopwatch

Can I get the elapsed time since I have called `Start` on a stopwatch using `ElapsedMilliseconds` without calling `Stop`? I have searched a lot round the internet but only saw examples where `ElapsedMilliseconds` is called after `Stop`. Is this value filled on a call to `Stop` or is it always correct?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> You can query the properties Elapsed, ElapsedMilliseconds, and ElapsedTicks while the Stopwatch instance is running or stopped. The elapsed time properties steadily increase while the Stopwatch is running; they remain constant when the instance is stopped.

— From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds#remarks

Comment: I am seeing 'interesting' (to put it nicely) situations where `watch.Elapsed.Ticks != watch.ElapsedTicks` so there is weird stuff going on inside Stopwatch. Caveat emptor. Guess I should have suspected that since ElapsedTicks is a property not a method. While I'm complaining, Stopwatch is not reliable on multi-core machines.

Comment: The statement retrieves the time twice.  If the stopwatch is running then of course it may change between those two retrievals.  [if you are seeing this after stopping the watch, then I'll grant you "weird" applies.

Comment: @DaleWilson the two properties mean something different; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432735/differences-in-elapsed-ticks-property-of-stopwatch)

Comment: If you call stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds twice in a row I doubt you'd be guaranteed the same result unless you had called .Stop() first.