# A Label in C# That has a long press

Tags: c#, label, long-press

Hi Ive got a label on my form that i want to press for 2.5 seconds before it does a function like display a message box I tried Using mouse down and mouse up but without success it didn't wait for the time i told it to. Anything would help.Thanks.

```
 private void Ltitelpress(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lTitel.MouseDown+=delegate(object o, MouseEventArgs args) {  };
       Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Start();
        timer.Interval = 2500;
        if (timer.Interval == 2500)
        {
        lTitel.MouseUp+= delegate(object a, MouseEventArgs args)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Good Job");
        };

        }
    }
```

the problem is i don't even no if this code is even close to accurrite

Comment: Post your code and folks can help fix it.

Comment: i posted it im pretty new to programming so I dunno if im off my rocker or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a Stopwatch at the class level (form Level) so you can access it from 2 different event procedures.

```
private Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            sw.Start();
        }
        private void label1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            sw.Stop();
            if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 2500)
                MessageBox.Show("Mouse held down long enough.");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Not long enough.");
        }
```

Comment: that helped alot

Answer (score 0):

Just move your codes to `MouseUP` event of the `Label` and it will fire only when you release the mouse click from the label

```
private void label_MouseUP()
///codes here
```

or if you wanna do it the hard way :)

```
private void label_MouseDown()
  var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
  double elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

   if (elapsedMs > 2500)
    { 
     ////codes here
    }
```

Comment: the problem is it always fires on the mouse up regardless of the timer

Comment: i want it to only fire when im holding it down

Comment: make sure to mark the answer as answer if it helped :)

Comment: @zackraiyan surely this is slightly incomplete as it would start the timer it would be 0 as elapsed and then 0 is always < 3500

Comment: As far i know, `ElapasedMilliseconds` can be queried also while the stopwatch is running..Take a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720813/should-i-call-stop-before-reading-elapsedmilliseconds)

Comment: and even the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds.aspx) says so .... :)